# fatal: Interactive git shell is not enabled. got the message fatal: Interactive git shell is not enabled

Tags: git, fedora, fedora16

I have run this command with root:

```
    [root@localhost git-shell-commands]# ssh git@192.168.1.12
    git@192.168.1.12's password: 
    Last login: Wed Jun 20 15:08:26 2012 from new-host.home
    fatal: Interactive git shell is not enabled.
    hint: ~/git-shell-commands should exist and have read and execute access.
    Connection to 192.168.1.12 closed.
    [root@localhost git-shell-commands]#
```

Anybody could told how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`git help shell` gives some pointers on how to set it up. The hint in the output also. The git user need a subdirectory called `git-shell-commands` in its home directory, with appropriate permissions, and populated with the things you want the user to be able to run.