# Git-shell: git-shell-commands should exist rather than "What do you think I am? A shell?"

Tags: git, ubuntu, repository

I'm trying to set up my Git server on Ubuntu 12.04 as described in [this document](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-4.html). I've got my SSH key working fine, and I've changed the shell of the Git account to use `/usr/bin/git-shell`.

According to the document, I should now expect to see "What do you think I am? A shell?", however, in actual fact I see the usual shell intro for ubuntu, followed by the following:

```
fatal: Interactive git shell is not enabled.
hint: ~/git-shell-commands should exist and have read and execute access.
```

As I understand it, if  I am to resolve the directory issue there I'll just end up with some git prompt rather than the message I am looking for.

Comment: hint: ~/git-shell-commands should exist and have read and execute access.

Comment: "As I understand it, if I am to resolve the directory issue there I'll just end up with some git prompt rather than the message I am looking for."

Comment: Check http://serverfault.com/questions/285324/git-shell-not-enabled .. Does it help?

Comment: Hard to say from remote. Let's wait if others have ideas. Otherwise I'm willing to set up my own (on virtualbox) and have a look

Comment: That would be really appreciated hek2mgl.

Comment: possible duplicate of [fatal: Interactive git shell is not enabled. got the message fatal: Interactive git shell is not enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120399/fatal-interactive-git-shell-is-not-enabled-got-the-message-fatal-interactive)

Comment: I know how to solve the directory error, Rudi, but that does not give me the message I am looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Git 1.7.4 just improved the functionality of git-shell, so now it presents itself differently.
See also https://github.com/git/git/commit/e69164ddb9d6092a94915bb984749d48f598cea8

You have set up your server correctly, as described in the document.

Answer (score 4):

Inside the source code dir there's a /contrib dir and inside you will find a /git-shell-commands/*
Copy that dir to the Home of git user and change owner for that dir and files inside.

It should work ok.